# How to create a classlibrary with TargetFramework=netstandard2.1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0, .net-standard-2.1

I have installed dotnet-sdk-3.0.100-win-x64.exe in my system to targeting .NET Core 3.0 application. Post installation I validated the installed version using the command : dotnet --version which is giving response = 3.0.100.

Now using dotnet cli I tried to create a classlibrary(C#) with targetframework=netstandard2.1 and also created a solution and added the classlibrary project to it.

On building the solution I see the following error:

**Error NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard 2.1.  Either target .NET Standard 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Standard 2.1. SampleApp   C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\2.2.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets**

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you installed the 2.1 SDK ? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1

Comment: Yes I have these versions of .NET SDK installed in my system: 2.1.700, 2.2.300, 3.0.100

Comment: Make sure that you don't have a `global.json` file in the current working directory or one of its parent directories. It may specify an older version of the SDK than the latest one installed on your machine. Apparently 2.2.300 is used.

Comment: It is a classlibrary project which does not have any global.json file at all

Comment: What if you do `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 3.0.100` before you build?

Comment: I am getting the below error now :                                                            
 Detailed Information:
Version 3.0.100 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.3.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 16.1.76.45076. Change the .NET Core SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro: See [this](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/4737) issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have a [`global.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) file in the current working directory or one of its parent directories.

It is used to define which .NET Core SDK version is used when you run .NET Core CLI commands. In your case, `2.2.300` is apparently used. If there is no `global.json`, the latest SDK installed on the machine should be used.

You can try to run this command just before you build to to create a new the `global.json` file in the current directory

```
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 3.0.100
```

Note that you need Visual Studio version 16.3 or greater to work with .NET Core 3. If it complains about MSBuild, try to update Visual Studio or/and see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/4737) issue on GitHub.

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro: Did you solve this or what happened?